# PHP Nested FOR Loops Troubleshooting

Tags: php, mysql, database, for-loop

I have a database with 10 columns in a row, each set to contain an image name.

himage1, himage2, himage3, etc...

The user can delete any of these images individually, and the corresponding column value is set to 'na', to signify that there is no image.

But say there are 3 images, which means that from 'himage4' onwards the fields are 'na', and the user deletes 'himage1', then the row will look like this:

himage1 = 'na', himage2 = "...img2.jpg", himage3 = "...im3.jpg", himage4 = 'na', himage5 = 'na', etc...

This creates a problem, as I have another column, 'hnumimage', which controls how many images are set to be displayed.

But if 'hnumimage' is 2, in this example, as there are only 2 images, the loop I use to display the images will still try to display 'himage1', even though it is blank.

For this reason I'm trying to create a function that will detect if a field is 'na', and then check if any of the following fields have a valid image. If so, move that image value forward.

So in the example above, it should look like this after the function is run:

himage1 = "...img2.jpg", himage2 = "...im3.jpg", himage3 = 'na', himage4 = 'na', himage5 = 'na', etc...

I'm using 2 nested for loops, but I'm having problems with the logic involved.

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {

// IF IMAGE FIELD IS NA
if ( $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $i ] == na ) {

    //CHECK FOLLOWING IMAGES
    for ( $o = $i + 1; $o <= 10; $o++ ) {

        // IF FOUND IMAGE VALUE
        if ( $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ] != na ) {

            // MOVE THAT VALUE FORWARD, and CLEAR OLD FIELD
            $vCurrImgVal = $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ];
            $sql_arrange_img = "UPDATE tblhome SET himage" . $i . " = '" . $vCurrImgVal . "', himage" . $o . " = 'na' WHERE hid = 1";

            $rs_arrange_img = mysqli_query( $vconn_db, $sql_arrange_img );

        }

    }

}
```

This works, but only once.

The example above would look like this:

himage1 = "...img3.php", himage2 = 'na', himage3 = 'na', himage4 = 'na', etc

The inner loop succesfully swaps 'himage1' with 'himage2', but then also compares 'himage1' with 'himage3' after that, so replaces it with 'himage3', leaving all the other fields blank.

I've identified this as the inner loop running even after 2 values have successfully been swapped, so I've tried breaking out of the inner loop on successful swap, but then the outer loop seems to still not work.

I know I'm missing something, and I've been stuck on this for a while.

Some insight into the logic and order involved in this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This table is not normalized. It would be better to store the images in another table and you wouldn't be facing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a nested loop is a very complicated way of doing this. And you have the problem that the array is changing while you search it. I would simply split it into two steps. First of all, get the data you want. Then get the rest.

And while you're at it, it's good practice to quote your string values (so `'na'` instead of `na`)

```
<?php

    $rs_home_delete_select_array=array('himage1' => 'na', 'himage2' => "...img2.jpg", 'himage3' => "...im3.jpg", 'himage4' => 'na', 'himage5' => 'na');
    $temp = array();


    $idx = 1;

    //Step 1 put data first
    for ( $o = $i + 1; $o <= 10; $o++ ) {
        if ( isset($rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ]) && $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ] != 'na' ) {
            $temp[ 'himage' . $idx ]  = $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ];
            $idx++;
        }
    }

    //Step 2. Put 'na' elements later
    for ( $o = $i + 1; $o <= 10; $o++ ) {
        if ( isset($rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ]) && $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ] == 'na' ) {
            $temp[ 'himage' . $idx ]  = $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ];
            $idx++;
        }
    }



    //Update DB
    foreach ($temp as $key => $val){
        $sql_arrange_img = "UPDATE tblhome SET `$key` = '$val' WHERE hid = 1";
        $rs_arrange_img = mysqli_query( $vconn_db, $sql_arrange_img );
    }


?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I tweaked this code and managed to get it working perfectly.

Comment: @FrancoViljoen. I'm glad it's working. Could you accept the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Add `break` to come out of the loop as soon as you find the next image to replace it.

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {

// IF IMAGE FIELD IS NA
if ( $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $i ] == na ) {

    //CHECK FOLLOWING IMAGES
    for ( $o = $i + 1; $o <= 10; $o++ ) {

        // IF FOUND IMAGE VALUE
        if ( $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ] != na ) {

            // MOVE THAT VALUE FORWARD, and CLEAR OLD FIELD
            $vCurrImgVal = $rs_home_delete_select_array[ 'himage' . $o ];
            $sql_arrange_img = "UPDATE tblhome SET himage" . $i . " = '" . $vCurrImgVal . "', himage" . $o . " = 'na' WHERE hid = 1";

            $rs_arrange_img = mysqli_query( $vconn_db, $sql_arrange_img );
            break; // add break to come out of the loop

        }

    }

}
```